# JavaFX ComboBox has strange Event behaviour when ENTER is pressed

Tags: java, javafx

I have a problem understanding the event behaviour of the JavaFX ComboBox when the ENTER key is pressed.

I've added an event handler and event filter both on the scene and the combobox listening on `KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED`. 
See the following example code:

```
ComboBox<String> cb = new ComboBox<>();
cb.getItems().addAll("Test", "hello", "world");

cb.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, event -> System.out.println("combobox filter"));
cb.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, event -> System.out.println("combobox handler"));

VBox root = new VBox(cb);         
Scene scene = new Scene(root);

scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, event -> System.out.println("scene filter"));
scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, event -> System.out.println("scene handler"));
```

When the combobox is focused and I'm pressing some letter key, I get this result:

```
scene filter
combobox filter
combobox handler
scene handler
```

This is the expected behaviour. First the filters are called from top to bottom. After that the handlers are executed from bottom to top. This is perfectly fine. However when I press the ENTER key I get the following result:

```
scene filter
combobox filter
scene filter
scene handler
combobox handler
```

I don't understand this behaviour.

Some sentenses about what I'm actually trying to implement:
We have a dialog with a form. The requirement is to close the dialog when the user presses the ENTER key, except there is a ComboBox opened at the moment. In this case only the ComboBox should be closed but the dialog should stay open.

I was trying to implement this with an EventHandler at the scene that closes the dialog on ENTER. On the ComboBox I was adding an EventFilter that consumes the event. The problem is that even if I consume the event in the comboBox' eventFilter, the eventHandler on the scene still get's executed due to the described behaviour.